# Under WIn7, how to streamline usage LibreCrypt?

Tags: windows-7, linux, usb, external-hard-drive, encryption

I work in linux occasionally using LUKS encryption on the command line. Wife works in Win7 with no encryption experience.

I need to encrypt a USB external hard drive from the linux command line, then copy files to it, then give it to her to use on her Win7 machines.

I have this up and running using LibreCrypt on her Win7 machines.  But too many steps are involved after plugging it in to Win7 machine.

I'd like to set things up on the Win7 machines so that when she uses the external hard drive I configed as above:

1) she is immediately prompted for the passphrase when she plugs in the USB hard drive.

2) she needs only eject the drive before unplugging it (no other steps required).

How can I set this up?

Comment: Bitlocker supports both of your requirements.

Comment: edited post: wish to streamline the Win7 experience when using a USB external hdd configured under linux using cryptsetup/LUKS